# Dropped frame even on the simpliest examples

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, game-development

I'm creating a canvas game and using Chrome profiler to find rendering and performance issues. But it shows lots of red block "Dropped Frame".

[image]

```js
      let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
      let c = canvas.getContext('2d')
      let dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1
      let {width, height} = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
      canvas.width = width * dpr
      canvas.height = height * dpr
      c.scale(dpr, dpr)
    
      let x = 100
      let y = 100
      document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
        x = event.clientX
        y = event.clientY
      })
    
      function render() {
        c.fillStyle = '#9be2fe'
        c.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)
        c.fillStyle = '#e23521'
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(x, y, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
        c.fill()
      }
      function main() {
        requestAnimationFrame(main)
        render()
      }
      main()
```

```css
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
    
            body {
                height: 100vh;
            }
    
            canvas {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>DEMO</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Even for most basic examples! What is wrong? And why are frames not the same size?

Comment: Are any extensions running?

Comment: Nope. Nope. Nope.

Comment: Navigate to chrome://gpu/ (you will need to type it in the address bar) to make sure you are using hardware to render. If there are problems you can try changing GPU related setting via chrome://flags/ (again must type it into address bar)